# CodenameOne Image.rotate90Degrees() does't work on iOS

Tags: image, rotation, codenameone

The Image.rotate90Degrees() doesn't work on iOS, it works on Simulator and Android.

The picture is OK on Nexus5 -Android

[[image: Nexus5]]

But it becomes a square with WHITE color at the bottom on iPhone6Plus:

[[image: iPhone6Plus]]

Here is the sample code:

```
public void start()
{
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));
    Label label = new Label();
    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, label);

    Image image = pictures.getImage("000008.jpg");

    Image imageNew = Image.createImage(Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight(), Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth());
    Graphics graphics = imageNew.getGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageNew.getWidth(), imageNew.getHeight());
    imageNew = imageNew.rotate90Degrees(false);
    label.setIcon(imageNew);

    hi.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the image is cloned anyway drawing it onto a new image is unnecessary. Generally using multi image's [slows down the application in iOS](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#areMutableImagesFast--).

It should work if you just do a `roateImage` on `image` itself. It's possible that the image is so large it exceeds some texture size threshold at some point since the 6+ is a very high DPI device.

Comment: Thanks Shai. It works when the image itself rotated.